# Flashing animation getting interrupted by DoEvents

Tags: excel, vba, dispose, repaint, doevents

I have written some simple code in Excel VBA, to make a range "flash" a colour - this is achieved by carefully drawing a rectangle object over the range in question, and varying its transparency to make the box fade gradually.

Here's the code (in `Sheet1` for the `Worksheet_Change` event):

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Sub flashBox(ByVal area As Range, Optional ByVal fillColour As MsoRGBType = vbGreen)

    Const animationSeconds As Single = 0.5
    Const animationSteps As Long = 20

    With area.Worksheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, area.Left, area.Top, _
                                        Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(area.Width, 1000), _
                                        Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(area.Height, 1000)) 'stop infinite boxes, could use view area to define this
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = fillColour
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To animationSteps
            Sleep animationSeconds * 1000 / animationSteps
            .Fill.Transparency = i / animationSteps
            DoEvents 'screen repaint
        Next i
        .Delete
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    flashBox Target, ColorConstants.vbMagenta
End Sub
```

I use a `With` block to contain the temporary object without a parent variable (I think it's quite neat and would hope to keep it this way). The issue arises from the `DoEvents` call (necessary to force a screen repaint for the animation).

The animation is called from certain worksheet change events, and if a second instance of the sub is called (or actually if any event happens it seems), the first one is terminated half complete, and never finishes - meaning the temporary shape is never deleted.

Here's an illustration showing what I'm talking about:
[image: Demo Gif]

How can I work around this?

Comment: @QHarr Sure, there's the caller code which is a `Worksheet_Change` event. The `DoEvents` is in the `For i.. Next` loop of the animation

Comment: oopsy! My bad for not seeing!

Comment: Not a solution, but you need to keep in mind that VBA runs on a single thread, meaning that the thread can either do one thing, or the other. If you're expecting the box to keep flashing (something that the main thread makes possible) while you call some other event (run a macro, update a screen etc.), I think you're going to have a hard time. Interesting question though!

Comment: Man it's moments like these where you wish vba supported multi-threading

Comment: @Rawrplus [Tell me about it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/185212/146810) ;) Although actually in this instance I think there might be a workaround

Comment: Very interesting, that `DoEvents` prevents the execution of the second half of your Sub at all! Workaround: Give the shape an `.AlternativeText = "DeleteMe"` to recognise and delete all of them in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's more of a workout than a solution, but it gets the job done, technically speaking

If you disable the userinput during the runtime of the `flashbox` procedure it will wait for the animation to finnish and only then  re-enable it, you steer clear of the animation staying frozen

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Interactive = False
    flashBox Target, ColorConstants.vbMagenta
    Application.Interactive = True
End Sub
```

[image]

I'll see if I can solve this "properly" but for now at last this is a nice workaround :)